# Why doesn't "text-align: left" work in Outlook?

Tags: html, css

We're using Salesforce Marketing Cloud to send emails to our subscribers. Left-aligned text doesn't work for Outlook even if I put
`<p style="text-align: left;">text</p>`.

I even tried using `word-spacing` CSS, but nothing worked for Outlook. All the text becomes `justify`-aligned.

How can I fix this?

Comment: try using single quote style='text-align: left;'

Comment: @jmag I tried, doesn't work